# MOSS 2007, programmatically downloading document folder; Can't connect to Document folder

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm attempting to programmatically download all files from a document folder on a Sharepoint 2007 site. So far, I'm able to connect to the site, but am having issues connecting to the folders and download them.

```
try{
    using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysharepointserver/sites/subsite")){
        using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()){
            Console.Write("Connected to site");
            SPFolder testFolder = web.Folder["testFolder"];
            //example method downloading folder
            downloadFolder(testFolder);
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    Log(e.ToString());
}
```

My console write works,so I know I am connecting to the site correctly.
My log file outputs:

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.GetListByName(String strListName, Boolean bThrowException)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.get_Item(String strListName)
```

I also attempted to print out the following:

```
using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()){
            Console.Write("Connected to site");
            Console.Write(web.lists);
            SPFolder testFolder = web.Folder["testFolder"];
            //example method downloading folder
            downloadFolder(testFolder);
        }
```

Which outputs the following to console:

```
Connected to site
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection
```

But I'm not certain how to navigate through SPListCollection to retrieve my folder "testFolder"

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you connect to share point site, there are different types of libraries. Library that contains documents and folders is DocumentLibrary and not ListLibrary. Once you have the item / library by ID, cast it to correct SPDocumentLibrary to retrieve items you want.

Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spdocumentlibrary?view=sharepoint-server to get different methods and properties of DocumentLibrary to retrieve the testFolder.

Example of accessing document library item from :https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5ee7fb55-5d90-4d28-8990-bf00479f891f/how-to-get-spdocumentlibrary?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

```
SPSite siteCollection = this.Site;
SPWeb site = this.Web;
// obtain query string values
string ListId = Request.QueryString["ListId"];
string ItemId = Request.QueryString["ItemId"];
// create list object and list item object
SPList list = site.Lists[new Guid(ListId)];
SPListItem item = list.Items.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(ItemId));
// query for information about list and list item
string ListTitle = list.Title;
string ItemTitle = item.Title;

if (list is SPDocumentLibrary) {
  SPDocumentLibrary documentLibrary = (SPDocumentLibrary)list;
  string DocumentTemplateUrl = documentLibrary.DocumentTemplateUrl;
  SPFile file = item.File;
  string FileAuthor = file.Author.Name;
  string FileSize = file.TotalLength.ToString("0,###") + " bits";
}
```